# pattern method matches returns false

Tags: java

I have

```
String b = "aasf/sdf/dfd/*";
Pattern.matches("[^ ]", b);
```

I keep getting returned false in Patter.matches();

Since it matches regex, all characters beside space character, shouldn't it return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern.matches` would try to match the pattern exactly..

So it would return `true` only if you have a **single** non space character as input.

Its like using `\A[^ ]\z`

where `\A` is the beginning of input and `\z` is end of input..

---

If you want to check for strings that doesn't contain space you can use

```
input.matches("[^ ]*");
```

Comment: @JungJoo see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) .It has all the different patterns supported by java...Have a look at `^`,`$`,`\A`,`\z` and their difference

Answer (score 1):

No, coz you try to match **whole** string to NON-SPACE character.

```
String b = "aasf/sdf/dfd/*";
Pattern.matches("[^ ]*", b);
```

This one will return true

Comment: oh i thought it was comparing the whole string as a single character. i guess it compares with each char within the string.

Comment: Almost certainly he wants a'+' rather than a '*', yes?

Comment: Could be. But does not matter for his case

Answer (score 1):

As anirudh suggested, Pattern matchers are used differently (see the other answers for examples), I believe that what you were trying to do is the following:

```
    String b = "aasf/sdf/dfd/*";
    System.out.println("b.matches(\"[^ ]\") = " + b.matches("[^ ]"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b.matches("[^ ]") = false
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.matches()` returns `true` only if the entire string matches the regex. What you want to do is to see if the pattern occurs anywhere in the `String`. You need to use `Matcher.find()` for that.

e.g,

```
    String testStr = "aasf/sdf/dfd/*";
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[^ ]");
    Matcher m = patt.matcher(testStr);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

This will print all matches. If you just need to know if a pattern is found, just check if `m.find()` is `true`.